# Рефакторинг на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, рефакторинг

Написал следующий код:

```
print ("--------------")
print ("--Calculator--")
print ("--------------\n")

print("Enter (Q)uit to exit.\n \n")

while True:
    que = input("Select an operation (+, -, *, /): ")

    if que == "+":
        try:
            num_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            num_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

            print("The answer is " , num_1 + num_2, "\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError. Try again.\n")



    elif que == "-":
        try:
            num_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            num_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

            print("The answer is " , num_1 - num_2, "\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError. Try again.\n")



    elif que == "*":
        try:
            num_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            num_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

            print("The answer is " , num_1 * num_2, "\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError. Try again.\n")



    elif que == "/":
        try:
            num_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            if num_1 == 0:
                print("Cannot be divided by zero. Try again.\n")
            else:
                num_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
                if num_2 == 0:
                    print("Cannot be divided by zero. Try again.\n")
                else:           
                    print("The answer is: " , num_1 / num_2, "\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError. Try again.\n")


    elif que == "Q":
        break

    else:
        print("Unknown value. Try again.\n")
```

Нетрудно заметить, что блоки постоянно повторяются. Не могу придумать, как запихнуть в функции, т.е. какие аргументы задать, чтобы менялся арифметический оператор между *num_1* и *num_2*. Зашёл в тупик, мне нужна помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import operator

OPERATORS = {
    '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul, '%': operator.mod,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}
OPERATORS_STR = ', '.join(OPERATORS.keys())


def main():
    print("--------------")
    print("--Calculator--")
    print("--------------\n")
    print("Enter (Q)uit to exit.\n \n")

    while True:
        task = input(f"Select an operation ({OPERATORS_STR}): ")

        if task in OPERATORS:
            try:
                num_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
                num_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
                result = OPERATORS[task](num_1, num_2)
                print(f"The answer is {result}\n")
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("Cannot be divided by zero. Try again.\n")
            except ValueError:
                print("ValueError. Try again.\n")

        elif task == "Q":
            break

        else:
            print("Unknown value. Try again.\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Улучшения:

- Поправил число пустых строк и число пробелов для улучшения стиля кода и сответствия рекомендациям PEP.
- Вынес всю логику в отдельную функцию, которая вызывается при запуске конкретно этого файла (`__name__ == '__main__'`).
- Вынес операторы и работу с ними в словарь. Использовал стандартный модуль операторов, можно также добавить кастомные функции или лямбы. Добавил ещё один оператор, чтобы показать, как теперь это легко.
- Список операторов теперь строится автоматически – меньше дублирования кода.
- Улучшил работу со строками используя f-строки из Python 3.
- Упростил обработку деления на ноль – тот же код сработает и для взятия модуля.

<sub>*За корректность ручаюсь, проверял*</sub>

Comment: Это, скажем так, не совсем рефакторинг. Но неплохо. =)

Answer (score 3):

Обязательно вынести непосредственно вычисления в отдельную функцию:

```
def calc(a, b, op):
    if op == '+':
        return a + b
    if op == '-':
        return a - b
    if op == '*':
        return a * b
    if op == '/':
        if b == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError('Cannot be divided by zero. Try again.')
        return a / b
    raise RuntimeError(f'Unknown operation {op}.')


while True:
    que = input("Select an operation (+, -, *, /): ")
    if que == "Q":
        break
    if que not in ('+', '-', '*', '/'):
        print(f'Unknown operation {que}. Try again.')
        continue

    try:
        num_1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num_2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
        result = calc(num_1, num_2, que)
        print(f'The answer is {result}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message if hasattr(e, 'message') else e)
```

<sub>*За корректность всего не ручаюсь, не проверял*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Код немного непонятный, но хорошо расширяемый. И еще... кажись я опоздал. Любая функция, соответствующая типу таска принимает в качестве аргумента строку таска. Иногда она игнорируется, но мы избавляемся от сложной логики, просто вызвав функцию для таска вслепую.

```py
import operator

OPERATORS = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '%': operator.mod,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}
INFO_WIDTH = 30
TEXTS = {
    'title':      "Calculator",
    'quit':       'Enter (Q)uit to exit.',
    'task input': f"Select an operation ({', '.join(OPERATORS.keys())}): ",
    'num input':  "Enter {} number: ",
    'ans':        "The answer is {}\n",
    'zero err':   "Cannot be divided by zero. Try again.\n",
    'value err':  "ValueError. Try again.\n",
    'unklown':    "Unknown value. Try again.\n"
}


def calc(task):
    try:
        num_1 = float(input(TEXTS['num input'].format('first')))
        num_2 = float(input(TEXTS['num input'].format('second')))
        result = OPERATORS[task](num_1, num_2)
        print(TEXTS['ans'].format(result))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print(TEXTS['zero err'])
    except ValueError:
        print(TEXTS['value err'])

TASKS = {
    lambda x: x in OPERATORS: calc,
    lambda x: x == 'Q': lambda x: quit()
}


def line(text=''):
    char = ['-' for _ in range(INFO_WIDTH)]
    pad_len = (INFO_WIDTH - len(text)) // 2
    char[pad_len: pad_len + len(text)] = list(text)
    print(''.join(char))


def main():
    line()
    line(TEXTS['title'])
    line(TEXTS['quit'])
    line()
    print()

    while 1:
        task = input(TEXTS['task input'])
        for _ in TASKS:
            if _(task):
                TASKS[_](task)
                break
        else:
            print(TEXTS['unklown'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).